# Автоматически добавлять префикс к строке EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

**Дано:**

Пользователь вводит текст(пару букв или 50 строк) в EditText, 
и для каждой строки автоматически добавляется префикс в виде какого-то символа, к примеру "*".

**Пример:**

- строка 1
- строка два

Answer (score 1):

Незнаю, правильно ли написал, но надо проверить) Попробуйте навесить на какую-нибудь кнопку эту логику.

```
 editText.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int lineCount = editText.getLineCount();
                String line;
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
                    int startPos = editText.getLayout().getLineStart(i);
                    int endPos = editText.getLayout().getLineEnd(i);
                    line = editText.getText().toString().substring(startPos, endPos);
                    stringBuilder.append("*").append(line);
                    stringBuilder.append("\n");
                }
                editText.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик. Но это не решение(